# How to create an OTA update for custom AOSP Rom?

Tags: android, auto-update, ota

We're developing our custom Android ROM and we're interested to provide Over-The-Air (OTA) updates to our clients. Can someone point me a detailed step-to-step on how to create an OTA update for a custom Android Open-Source Project (AOSP)? I've already read the Google [**documentation**](https://source.android.com/devices/tech/ota/index.html) but I haven't understood it very well.

PS: at current moment we're able to compile our custom Android OS ROM with success, and flash it to the device with no problem.

Comment: Did you find any solution?

Answer (score 5):

Not really the official way, but [this project](https://github.com/tgalal/inception) does a similar thing.

Answer (score 1):

to create an OTA update for your custom ROM, you need target file, when you create your rom, inside

> out/target/product/device_name/obj/PACKAGE/target-something/

you will have the 'target.zip' file. you have to use this file to create your OTA package. you have to pass the target.zip file to a script called

> ota_from_target_files.py

this script is usually at

> builds/tools/releasetools/ota_from_target_files.py

you can use this script to create both Full OTA updates and Incremental OTA updates.

when you created your OTA package, you can sideload it or place it in your Updater backend to install your new ROM using updater application.